# The memory limit setting may be not respected by cobalt

Tags: cobalt

From the cobalt memory [docs](https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/rc_11/src/cobalt/doc/memory_tuning.md) , we set `max_cobalt_cpu_usage` limit to **250M**, `max_cobalt_gpu_usage` to 150M, and found the actual max memory used by cobalt is about **370M** when play the 4K videos for about 12 hours, it exceeded 250M a lot, so what kind of memory(eg. *malloc/new/mmap* etc.) is counted into `max_cobalt_cpu_usage`? How to set the `max_cobalt_cpu_usage` and keep the actual memory usage within the `max_cobalt_cpu_usage`?

```
PS.The memory statistical approach is as follows:
1>Move focus to the cobalt icon, drop the memory cache, record the memory free value(memoryBegin) from /proc/meminfo;
2>Enter cobalt youtube, and keep playing 4K videos for about 12 hours;
3>During playing the videos, record the memory free value(memoryEnd) from /proc/meminfo every 10s(drop the memory cache before record the memory);
4>Find the minimum memoryEnd as  memoryEndMin;
5>memoryBegin - memoryEndMin = 370M;
```

Answer (score 0):

> what kind of memory(eg. malloc/new/mmap etc.) is counted into max_cobalt_cpu_usage?

The value returned from `SbSystemGetUsedCPUMemory()` is used to determine the current cpu memory usage. Please ensure that this returns the expected values.

Note that the cache's won't dynamically re-size to keep within the limits. The initial conditions must be set to account for the maximum memory limit that is required to be set.

You can manually reduce the sizes of your caches (see memory_tuning.md document) or you can use --reduce_cpu_memory_by=Xmb which will allow the `AutoSet` memory settings to reduce their memory usage.

For more information about memory use, use --memory_tracker as a command line argument.